# Equiangular spherical knot projection

Tags: knot-theory

For which knots is there a projection to the 2-sphere (with finitely many double points corresponding to crossings) so that the arcs of the projection are geodesic and the two undercrossing arcs make equal angles with the overcrossing arc at each crossing (see the diagram)?

[image: undercrossing arcs make equal angles with the overcrossing arc]

The reason that I am curious about this is that such a diagram gives a representation of a knot group into $O(3)$ in which each meridian corresponding to an arc of the diagram maps to a reflection in the great circle containing the arc, and the equal angle condition corresponds to the Wirtinger relation of the crossing. Thus the knot projection encodes the representation of the knot group in a certain sense. I think that 2-bridge knots will not have such projections because every such representation is dihedral, so all the geodesics will meet in a pair of antipodal points. On the other hand, a [result of Kronheimer-Mrowka](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2805599) implies that such representations exist for any knot.

Comment: IanAgol: are you asking for a characterisation of all knots admitting such a diagram, or about "interesting" families?

Comment: Mostly I’m interested in seeing some pictures of some special examples (if they exist), but the question had to be formulated as a math question. So a valid answer might not provide an explicit picture.