# Equiangular piecewise circular knot projection

Tags: knot-theory

Inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450519/1345): say that a circle (or line) $c$ is equiangular with circles/lines $a, b$ if the three circles/lines intersect in two points and $c$ makes equal angles with $a$ and $b$.

[image]

For which knots is there a projection to the plane (with finitely many double points corresponding to crossings) so that the arcs of the projection are arcs of circles or line segments and the two undercrossing arcs make equal angles with the overcrossing arc at each crossing (see the diagram)?

[image]

Such a projection of a knot should correspond to a representation of the knot group into conformal (Möbius) transformations of the sphere such that each meridian associated to an arc of the diagram goes to inversion in the corresponding circle (or reflection in line). The Wirtinger relation associated to each crossing means that inversion in the overcrossing circle $c$ will exchange $a$ and $b$, conjugating the corresponding inversions.

If there is a positive answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/450519/1345) for a knot, then one gets a positive answer to this question by stereographic projection.